# Correlation of events in Red Lights

Tags: plot-explanation, red-lights

This is about the movie *Red Lights* (2012).

Is there any correlation between the deaths of Margaret and the skeptic reporter who both die of heart attacks. Or is it simply coincidence?

Answer (score 1):

I just watched Red Lights, like two-three days ago. If I understood what I was seeing, there IS a correlation between the two events. Tom Buckley. He didn't have conscious knowledge of, or control over his abilities. He hadn't ever acknowledged that he **had** abilities, not even to himself, except by jokingly saying he was psychic at one point. The fact that it was him all along is the big reveal at the very end.

Comment: You think Tom was responsible for the heart attacks?

Comment: Tom comes straight out and **says** it; right? At the very end. There's that montage then, while he does the closing narration, that shows all those mysterious occurrences that inexplicably took place throughout the film. And he says, "It was always me... "

Comment: Yes, it's clear that Tom is psychic. He causes all the strange happenings. But in both heart attacks he's nowhere around the victims. The first heart attack victim was 30 years ago, Tom wasn't even around for that one, no?

Comment: There's no indication as to just how long Tommy had been around, or how old he was, but it's clear he was a lot older than college age. Dr Matheson makes a few remarks that indicated that there was a big age difference between him and Sally Owen. It's also clear that Tommy did not need to be anywhere "around". to do psychic things. He could create strange effects from quite a distance..He was nowhere near  Dr Matheson when he bent the spoon in her coffee cup. He read her mind from however far away she was when he and Sally Owen were watching her doing that TV interview.

Comment: Of course I could also make a case for the argument that both deaths were due to natural causes... coincidences. Certainly re: Dr. Matheson, a few times she's seen taking some kind of pills, which she gets from what appears to be a bottle w/a prescription label on it. This indicates that she had some kind of medical condition. But then again, at one point we're shown a film where some psychic ostensibly explodes a frog's heart, which suggests such things might be doable.

Comment: Ah yes, I was just getting to the apparent heart problems Margaret already had. That is why I'm looking to see if there was any conclusive evidence or is it left to interpretation?

Comment: Thinking on all that business with the sleight of hand, the magic tricks, the references to how such tricks succeed... I figured out that we were intentionally being distracted throughout the film, misled w/tricky visual "clues" into always looking in the wrong direction. The film's creators were deliberately trying to confuse us, but I came away with the understanding that it was Tommy all along. Because he says that it was.